# "the Department of Sociology of Oxford University" or "Oxford University Department of Sociology "

Tags: phrases

"The Department of Sociology of Oxford University"

or

"Oxford University Department of Sociology "

Could I say the above phrases? Are they correct?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context.  Is the meant to on an address of a letter, or is it part of a sentence?

Comment: It is impossible to know without knowing the context. In many cases you will need to refer to the relevant style guide for the guidance you seek.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the phrase you want is "The Department of Sociology at the University of Oxford".

However when the context is clear, then "Oxford University, Department of Sociology" or just "Department of Sociology" might be enough

> The Department of Sociology at the University of Oxford, unlike others in the UK, ..."

If you are addressing a letter, then just "Department of Sociology, 42-43 Park End Street, Oxford" is correct.